# Geoflutter returns duplicate snaps

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, geofire

For some reason this code (using [GeoFlutterFire](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire)) returns me a duplicate of each DocumentSnapshot in my Firestore database:

```
Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream = await geo
        .collection(collectionRef: firestore.collection(structuresCollection))
        .within(center: center, radius: radius, field: field);

stream.listen((List<DocumentSnapshot> docList) async {
      placeModel = await updateList(docList);
      _placeFetcher.sink.add(placeModel);
      print('Place model: ${placeModel}');
    });
```

I've tried to debug it and duplication starts from here, but this is just a simply query, I don't really understand what's wrong with it

As you can see length is 14, it should be 7, every snap is duplicated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQs2j.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChvpJ.png)

Comment: it looks like geo is being updated as the stream gets new data when you update and add in real time.

Comment: Actually it might be some library problem, I found out that if radius is greater than some value it behaves like this

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I found the bug and fixed it. It was because of an edge case not handled by the lib, which created a duplicate query.

For large query radius, when the lib generates the list of "neighboring geohashes", it actually returns a list containing all neighbors **AND** the original (1-character) geohash, instead of returning only the neighbors hashes.

To fix it (until [this issue](https://github.com/DarshanGowda0/GeoFlutterFire/issues/57) has been patched by lib maintainor) you can update your **pubspec.yaml** file to fetch my fixed branch:

```yaml
geoflutterfire:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/Thibault2ss/GeoFlutterFire
      ref: fix-duplicate-results-on-large-radius
```

Cheers